# Kafka - when this happens - the committed offset is larger than the offset of the last message the client actually processed

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am going through the definitive guide and come across this phrase

> If the committed offset is larger than the offset of the last message
>   the client actually processed, all messages between the last processed
>   offset and the committed offset will be missed by the consumer group.

Wondering when this happens ? I understood the other use case where the committed offset is smaller, in which the consumer would have down leaving it not to commit the latest offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't happens from the normal consumption of messages.

I just checked the book, and a few pages later it explains how to commit a provided, arbitrary offset.

The reason why it's mentioned there is to make the point that the client can jump back and forth. I cannot think of a good reason when this would be used other that having to replay some messages due to an error, so an app could jump back and forth the stream replaying a few messages here and there.

Comment: right, i was thinking of the same as the the offset is "already committed" and wont care if the broker is down or consumer is down.

Comment: Another reason to "fastforward" is if you have a poison pill message. In that scenario it's possible to "skip" the message by changing the commited offset. This becomes really fun (not really) when for some reason invalid messages end up in a record stream.

Comment: How do we know if it is poison pill message unless we read it , just off topic

Comment: By the trail of exceptions in the logs and the monitoring tools firing alerts :D. As you said, the message is read, then there's a failure to deserialise it or process it. Usually at this point the app would log something that would trigger an alert. Since kafka gurantees ordering, it cannot proceed to the next message, so it tries the same message again, and again and again...

Comment: hmm, right - i think this where we will tend use "dead queues" pattern to hold this invalid messages and move on ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a possibility when auto commit is enabled and the actual processing of the messages, e.g, DB save, making call to another downstream systems etc, takes longer than than the auto-commit duration (value set for auto.commit.interval.ms). In happy path scenario this won't be a problem but in error case you may want to poll the same messages again. For this reason I disabled auto-commit for use case in my project and used to manually commit the offset once "actual processing" is done.

Comment: you mean the offset is commited but the message is NOT really processed and the consumer goes offline. And the next time, the next time consumer comesup, the downstream systems will poll the message again as the message is NOT processed ?

Comment: Yes that's also a scenario. Consider this,1)  Consumer polled and received messages from 0-5 offset, 2) Then those messages go through processing logic, eg save to DB and the save to DB fail 3) in the meanwhile the offset has already been auto-committed, so next time you would get messages from 6 and onwards. Now because you processing failed you would want to poll the messages again so you can retry but would not be able to as the offset has already been committed.

Comment: when you say "meanwhile the offset has already been auto-committed" - does it happen "automatically" in the background independent of poll loop ?